# How to make a messagebox auto close in several seconds by Python?

Tags: python

I already know how to make a Messagebox by Python:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, 'test', "Reminding", 0)
```

However, I want it to be closed by itself in several seconds after it shows up.

Is there any method to realize it?

Psuedo code:

```
def AutoCloseMessageBoxW(text, title, close_until_seconds)
```

I have found a lot of methods to realize this by other language such as C# and Java.

But I just can't find any method to realize it by Python.

Comment: The standard Windows message box, which you are invoking via `user32`, doesn't have any built-in self closing mechanism. If C# and Java allow this, it's because they created their own implementation of a message box that works differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
import threading
import time
#ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, 'test', "Reminding", 0)

def worker(title,close_until_seconds):
    time.sleep(close_until_seconds)
    wd=ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowA(0,title)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageA(wd,0x0010,0,0)
    return

def AutoCloseMessageBoxW(text, title, close_until_seconds):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=(title,close_until_seconds))
    t.start()
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, text, title, 0)


AutoCloseMessageBoxW('112','TEST_CLOSE',3)
```

Comment: Code dumps, while they may provide a solution, can be unclear for someone trying to learn from them. Can you describe in a few words the key elements of your approach and how/why it works?

Comment: It is very dangerous to have a thread that kills a window by its title, since titles aren't guaranteed to be unique. In particular if you get a second message box after the user has dismissed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

**Use pyautogui**

```
import pyautogui as py    # pip install pyautogui
            
# It is automatically terminated after three seconds. If automatically ends, return "Timeout" returns.
def show_message():
    res = py.confirm(text='Message...', buttons=['Yes', 'No'], timeout=3000)
    print(res)
```